# Cordova Inappbrowser multiple windows issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a problem with Cordova Inappbrowser (phonegap).
Example:

```
var bot1, bot2;    //windows

function createb1(){ //create window1
    bot1 = window.open(encodeURI("http://yandex.ru?b=1"), '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
    bot1.val = "bot1";
    bot1.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {  //add listener
        console.log("B1 loadstop " + event.url);
        $.get("js/embed.js", function(data){
           bot1.executeScript({code: data});
        });
    });
}

function createb2(){  //create window 2
        bot2 = window.open(encodeURI("http://yandex.ru?b=2"), '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
        bot2.val = "bot2";
        bot2.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {  //add listener
            console.log("B2 loadstop " + event.url);
            $.get("js/embed.js", function(data){
                bot2.executeScript({code: data});
            });
        });
};

function goB1(){  //go page window 1
        console.log(bot1);
        bot1.executeScript({code: "goPage('http://yandex.com.ua?b=1');"});
}

function goB2(){  // go page window 2
    console.log(bot2);
    bot2.executeScript({code: "goPage('http://yandex.com.ua?b=2');"});
}
```

embed.js

```
function goPage(page){
    window.location.href = page;
}
```

Console:

```
> createb1();
  B1 loadstop http://www.yandex.ru/?b=1
> goB1();
  InAppBrowser {channels: Object, val: "bot1", _eventHandler: function, close: function, show: function…}
  *B1 loadstop http://www.yandex.ru/ua/?b=1*
> createb2();
  B2 loadstop http://www.yandex.ru/?b=2
> goB1();
  InAppBrowser {channels: Object, val: "bot1", _eventHandler: function, close: function, show: function…}
  **B2 loadstop http://www.yandex.ru/ua/?b=1**
```

When I created window2 (bot2) - window1 (bot1) lost the handler. Why did it happen? How can I catch events in bot1 handler instead of bot2?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue, I'm using window.open to open an url in the system browser, and then my app looses the handler for the inappbrowser. (I need to use both at the same time)

Comment: @Publicus, sorry for late response. As I remember - Inappbrowser plugin allows you open only single instance because it is just a webview in a dialog. There is only one instance of dialog and wv. You can copy-paste their plugin and make little changes in it (create your own plugin with treir's code) - then you will have 2 plugins that's mean you can open 2 webviews =)

Comment: @Publicus See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660465/276648 Basically add all the events from your _blank InAppBrowser to your _system InAppBrowser.