# Opening two instances of InAppBrowser (_system and _blank) prevents events from triggering

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

We’re currently developing an app with cordova and the InAppBrowser plugin. We're trying to spawn two different IAB instances at the same time. One with the _system browser and another with the _blank option.

The problem we have is that once we open the instance of _system browser, it seems we lose the reference to the previous browser. For this reason, the close event never triggers on the _blank IAB after the _system browser is closed.

This is how the actual code looks like.

```
// Opening iab main window
var ref = window.open(global.chat_mediador, '_blank','location=no,toolbar=yes');

var handleEvents =  function(event) {

    // Closing the iab window 
    if (event.url.match('#close')) {
        ref.close();
    }

    // Trigger custom event
    if (event.url.match('#openccard')) {
        window.open('https://www.test.example.url.com?customerID=' + event.customerId, '_system', 'location=yes');
    }

}

// InAppBrowser events

// This events are duplicated because loadstop works on android and
// loadstart works on ios.
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvents, false);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', handleEvents, false);

// Removing the dialog when we close the chat
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    generali.dialog.close();
}, false);
```

As you can see we open the first url within the application with the _blank option. Then if in the child application a button is pressed we want to open an instance of a browser in the _system browser.

We’ve tried (without luck) to:

**Have a separate reference for the _system browser.**

```
window.open(global.url_ficha + customerId, '_system','location=no');
var cardsRef = window.open(
    'https://www.test.example.url.com?customerID=' + customerId,
    '_system', 
    'location=yes'
);
```

**Trigger a custom event outside the reference of the _blank browser**

```
 if (event.url.match('openccard')) {
     var customerId = event.url.split('openccard-')[1];
     var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
     evt.initEvent("openccard",true,true);
     evt.customerId = customerId;
     document.dispatchEvent(evt);
 }
```

Anyone has an idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you need to initialize the IAB each time you do a new window.open() if you don't do that the event listeners don't work.

If I use that code it works like a charm.

```
window.openIAB = function(url, target, options) {

    var self = this;
    var ref = window.open(url, target, options);

    var handleChildEvents = function(ev) {

        if (ref != undefined) {

            // Closing the iab window 
            if (ev.url.match('#close')) {
                ref.close();
                ref = undefined;
            }

            // Opening card url with system browser
            if (ev.url.match('#openccard')) {
                var customerId = ev.url.split('#openccard-')[1];
                self.ref2 = self.openIAB(
                    'https://www.test.com?customerID=' + customerId,
                    '_system', 
                    'location=yes'
                );
            }

        } else {
            console.log('InAppBrowser has no reference');
        }

    };

    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', handleChildEvents);
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', handleChildEvents);

    ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(ev) {
        console.log('error while loading page');
        ref.close();
        ref = undefined;
    });

    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(ev) {
        dialog.close();
    });

    return ref;
};
```

Comment: I have reported this bug to apache. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13198 I hope they atleast update their documentation.