# In App Browser open link in new tab in ionic 3 PWA

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 PWA on my website. It is an app for woocommerce. I use in app browser to complete payment inside my ionic app. Everything works fine when running the app on android or ios. But when I use the app as PWA or web app in the app browser, Open the required URL in a new tab which should not happen as in app browser officially supports browser.
Please help with any solution or workaround.

Comment: share your code of inAppBrowser.

Comment: var options = "location=no,hidden=yes,hideurlbar=yes";
            let browser = this.iab.create(results.redirect, '_blank', options);
            browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(data => {
                browser.show();

                this.buttonSubmit = false;
            });

Answer (score 2):

Did you try, to open URL with blank in app browser

```
InAppBrowser('url', '_blank');
```

Comment: Yes , its opening every url in new tab in browser instead of inappbrowser . I even tried changing the urls

Comment: could you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267276/opening-blank-links-inside-inappbrowser

Comment: I debugged my app. When inappbrowser is opened , the following error is thrown .  Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: browser_1.on(...).subscribe is not a function
TypeError: browser_1.on(...).subscribe is not a function
    at