# Cordova multiple InAppBrowser to manage internal/external links

Tags: cordova, multiple-instances, inappbrowser

I need to manage two different inAppBrowser instances to manage internal and external links. I had the same issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964619/cordova-inappbrowser-multiple-windows-issue) so I try to "can copy-paste their plugin and make little changes in it" as suggested in one of the answer.

This is what i've done so far:

- copy-paste the entire plugin folder
- I edited plugin.xml, package.json and /www/inappbrowser.js to obtain a new constructor (InAppBrowser2)

At the moment I see the new *cordova.InAppBrowser2* plugin/constructor in the console and I'm able to open a new window but this seems to not solve my original problem (when i open the second page, i lost event handler on the first one).

So, the question is: am I missing something in the plugin editing or is this approch not the right one for my purpose?

Thank you in advance

Mik

Comment: Ignoring that this is pretty weird way to go about this problem. I believe you will need to edit native code as well, there are definitely some handlers that could get overwritten.

Comment: Yeah, i know it's a wired and dirty way....do you have any suggestion for a better approach?

Comment: SOLVED in another way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652869/opening-two-instances-of-inappbrowser-system-and-blank-prevents-events-from